# Using print screen to print a title and barcode is working only on design mode

Tags: printing, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, barcode-printing

I have this screen with these settings inside my power apps canvas application:-

Height = 100

Width = 200

and inside the screen i have a button named "Print", with this formula:-

```
Print();
```

now on design mode >> the screen looks as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1711115589428.png]

and when i click on Print >> i will get this inside the print preview:-

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1711115609991.png]

and i can print it .

but on run time >> the screen will be as follow :-

[image: johnjohnPter_2-1711115728444.png]

and when i click on the Print button >> i will get this result were almost 90% of the text and barcode are not shown:-

[image: johnjohnPter_3-1711115748462.png]

any advice? why this is working on design mode but not on run mode?

Thanks